# How to test if all headers in the project are self-contained with CMake?

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I want to automatically test whether all headers in the project can be built on their own. This is a common technique to check whether headers include all their dependencies. Unfortunately I couldn't find how this can be achieved. Maybe someone could help? Being CMake newbie I'm not sure I can engineer a solution myself.

Hopefully a solution won't need generating any new `.cc` files or running any external scripts.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'building headers'?

Comment: `g++ <cflags, ldflags, etc> -c file.h`. This is a common technique to check whether a header includes all its dependencies.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the CMake commands `add_custom_target()` and `add_custom_command()`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the standard CMake module functions [CheckCXXSourceCompiles](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#module%3aCheckCXXSourceCompiles) and [CheckCSourceCompiles](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#module%3aCheckCSourceCompiles). Both functions check if a given (inline) source code compiles and links properly. To test if a header is self-contained, the source code needs to consist of an include statement that includes the header file to test and a main function:

```
include (CheckCXXSourceCompiles)

set (CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")   
check_cxx_source_compiles(
"#include \"file.h\"
int main() { return 0;}" File_H_IsSelfContained)
message ("File_H_IsSelfContained: ${File_H_IsSelfContained}")
```

Both `check_cxx_source_compiles` and `check_c_source_compiles` can only run at CMake configure time, which is probably not what you want.

Because both functions use the underlying CMake command `try_compile`, which is not scriptable, it is not possible to use the functions in a generated CMake script that is run as a custom target at build time.